# Cant install Media module with Lightning distro conflict

Tags: 8, media

I am using lightning-8.x-2.10 and this distro comes with a few of the dependent modules already enabled. So I installed whatever needed modules did not come already with lightning. When I try to enable Media I first check the description next to the title and I see there are no missing module so I enable and save then I get this error. I do not get this error if I enable Media on a plain Drupal 8 site. This only happens when using Lightning.

```
Unable to install Media, core.entity_form_display.media.document.default, core.entity_form_display.media.image.default, core.entity_form_display.media.instagram.default, core.entity_form_display.media.tweet.default, core.entity_form_display.media.video.default, core.entity_view_display.media.document.default, core.entity_view_display.media.image.default, core.entity_view_display.media.instagram.default, core.entity_view_display.media.tweet.default, core.entity_view_display.media.video.default, field.field.media.document.field_document, field.field.media.document.field_media_in_library, field.field.media.image.field_media_in_library, field.field.media.instagram.field_media_in_library, field.field.media.tweet.field_media_in_library, field.field.media.video.field_media_in_library, field.storage.media.field_document, field.storage.media.field_media_in_library, media_entity.bundle.document, media_entity.bundle.image, media_entity.bundle.instagram, media_entity.bundle.tweet, media_entity.bundle.video already exist in active configuration.
```

I was able to fix this by going to the config sql table and deleting all of entities listed in the error:
core.entity_form_display.media.document.default
core.entity_form_display.media.image.default
,,,
,,,

Comment: I don't understand what the "Media" module is that you're trying to install. Lightning includes everything needed for Lightning Media to be enabled. You shouldn't need to enable a separate "Media" module.

Comment: I had to install Media 8.x-1.x-dev
https://www.drupal.org/project/media/releases?api_version%5B%5D=7234

I also had to install a few other dependencies like:
slick_media
image_widget_crop
blazy

I noticed a module inside Lightning here:
profiles/lightning/modules/lightning_features/lightning_media/
But is that the Media Module?

Comment: I believe the Lightning Media module is different than the Media Module here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/media/releases?api_version%5B%5D=7234
I could not create Media Bundles and manage media with the Lightning Media module. But after I installed the Media module the  media area - /admin/content/media looks different and I was able to create Entity referenced media fields and manage all images from the Library. Should I try to do this with the built in Media module from Lightning?

Comment: You definitely don't need the old Media module. That's completely unsupported and not a part of Lightning Media.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the information. I think that Media will become a part of Drupal core in 8.2.4? Or the next version. What will Lightning do then? Remove Lightning Media from its distro?

Comment: Media Entity was committed to the 8.4.x branch last week. That is one small part of Lightning Media. Lightning Media will continue to exist and will provide the necessary update path when 8.4.0 is released this fall.